# Adding JTable to a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I am trying to add a JTable to a JScrollPane. But I can't see the Table after doing this.

```
scrollpane.setBounds(100,50,800,400);
JTable table = new JTable(myTableModel(res));
scrollpane.add(table);
```

What's wrong with me?

Comment: Have you added `scrollpane` to your frame/panel?

Comment: For more details see [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating **ever** - that's the exclusive task of a suitable LayoutManager

Comment: `scrollpane.setBounds(100,50,800,400);`  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JTable doesn't show after adding JScrollPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911857/jtable-doesnt-show-after-adding-jscrollpane)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

scrollpane.setBounds(100,50,800,400);

```
JTable table = new JTable(myTableModel(res));

scrollpane.setViewporView(table);
```

Comment: no need to reproduce the incorrect manual sizing/locating, is there :-)

Answer (score 6):

> scrollpane.add(table);

- [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) isn't designated to nest any JComponent, you have to add [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to its JViewport, see also [Constructor Sumary in JScrollPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) as the proper way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JTable table = new JTable(myTableModel(res));
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollpane.setBounds(100,50,800,400);
```

Comment: no need to reproduce the incorrect manual sizing/locating, is there :-)